# IOS, How to close UIPickerView when item in UIPickerView is tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIPickerView, i used UIToolBar with UIBarButtonItem to close the UIPickerView when selected an item in the UIPickerView. But this didn't work as i found out that you cannot do this in custom views.

So just wanted to ask how i would solve this?

Here is the code when i set up the UIPickerView in an custom UIView:

```
-(void)setupPickerView:(NSDictionary*)dic{

            NSDictionary *category = [dic objectForKey:@"category"];
            pickerViewData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            NSString *c_ID;
            NSString *c_Name;

            for(NSDictionary *dict in category)
            {
            if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"C_ID"] != [NSNull null]){

                c_ID = [dict objectForKey:@"C_ID"];
            }
            if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"C_Name"] != [NSNull null]){
                c_Name = [dict objectForKey:@"C_Name"];

            }

            [pickerViewData addObject:c_Name];

            }

            pickerViewCatergory = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 140, 320, 300)];
            pickerViewCatergory.delegate = self;
            pickerViewCatergory.dataSource = self;
            pickerViewCatergory.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
            //pickerView.hidden = YES;
            [pickerViewCatergory setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            [pickerViewCatergory reloadAllComponents];
            [self.viewCreateThread addSubview:pickerViewCatergory];

        }
```

Comment: Provide us sample project so that we can see whats going on, i think there must be logical error, in view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your logic, the basic way to get rid of a `pickerView` after selecting an item in the `pickerView` would be by making good use of the `UIPickerViewDelegate` method `-didSelectRow:inComponent:`

Example:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    //store selected row index or relevant data
    //...
    //then get rid of pickerView
    [pickerView removeFromSuperview]; //simple way to just get rid of it
}
```

Comment: @redoc01 : well... this is the place to do it nonetheless. however, if you specify more information on how you are displaying the `pickerView`, it's hierarchy stuff then I or someone else can be more helpful. Anyways... how would you have wanted to hide the `pickerView` from that `UIToolbar` of yours in the first place?